# Why the space complexity of find LCA is O(1)?

Tags: tree, time-complexity, binary-tree

I read the second (or third) solution for finding LCA:

[Lowest Common Ancestor in a Binary Tree | Set 1](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lowest-common-ancestor-binary-tree-set-1/)

In the solution (second or third solution - without vector) they used Node* In order to save the LCA from left or right tree.

I think the space complexity need to bee LOG(N) because each 
step in the tree (in the stack) they create pointer or two pointers (Node*) till they found the solution.

Am I right ?

Comment: What is place complexity? You mean space complexity? Or time complexity?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for if you already figured it out though.